# How to set control property with amixer command line utility in linux?

Tags: linux, alsa

I am using amixer command line utility to set the property of mixer control. I am trying to set property on my default card (sound  card no. 0).

With the try I set one of the PCM property with command `amixer set PCM 90`. And got successful response with below output.

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 90 [71%] [-18.50dB]
  Front Right: Playback 90 [71%] [-18.50dB]
```

But with the another property "HP DAC", I applied same type command `amixer set HP DAC 90`. But no output came like PCM. And also property value had not been changed.

Note: With the (alsamixer) graphical view of amixer utility, I can able to change the property value of "HP DAC".

Can someone please give suggestion what extra need to do or correction in this to change the value of "HP DAC" property through amixer command line utility.

Answer (score 2):

The shell uses spaces to delimit parameters, so control names containing spaces must be quoted:

```
amixer set "HP DAC" 90
```